# Flat File Source Failing When Deployed and Executed

Tags: ssis, ssms, sql-server-data-tools, flat-file

I am trying to create a simple SSIS package that can be deployed to a VM on another domain (same computer) that has SSIS on it. The package that I have created will transfer data if I simply run the data flow from SSDT on the source computer, but when I try to deploy and execute it, it appears to have 2 errors. The first being that it cannot open the datafile "C:\SSIS\Product Data.txt". The second being that the Flat Files Source 1 failed the pre-execute phase. I think that the second error is caused from the first. Does anyone know how to create a package that can transfer data to another computer without the flat file source?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

C:\SSIS.... will refer to the local C drive of the computer that is executing the package.  So if you have it on the VM it would be at the \VM\C$.  Typically it means 1 of 2 things.

1) The file path is not correct and you are not referencing where the file actually is.

2) the user you are executing the package as does not have permission to that file.

So where is the file is it on the C drive of the machine you are executing the SSIS package on?  The answer to that wasn't clear in your question.

Second how is the file being executed?  manual execution such as DTS_Exec? SQL Agent? T-SQL?  If manual then the user logged in executing the task must have permission, if SQL Agent then the sql agent service account and possible the sql server service account have to have permission to the file, and T-sql sql server service account needs to have permission.

When it is local file path then a local user or domain user will work for the service accounts.  If network path then the local user used for service account won't work and you will need to setup a way to run as a different credential.

Comment: After working on it more I think that the issue is that the VM does not have access to the file. The connection string in SSMS is just the path to the file on the source computer. I could not find the data from the file anywhere on the VM where it is being executed. I need the VM to be able to execute the package as if it were not connected to the source. Do you know of a way to send the file over with deployment? I am fairly sure that that would fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how you would do it via deployment that is probably something you can google, it will depend on what type of deployment model you are using (project or package).  Via SSIS File System Task or Script Task it is pretty easy to move it from one to the other, but you do mention they are in different domains so that makes it more difficult....